# Ideas to compare two files line by line in python

Tags: python, file, comparison

I have sets of txt files in two different directories. Lets say dir 1 has file one.txt, two.txt..ten.txt. And dir 2 has file one.txt, two.txt..ten.txt. I want to compare content of files having same name, i.e one.txt and one.txt.
The one.txt file in dir 1 is:

```
**705.95 117.81 1242.00 252.43** 5.02
**1036.12 183.52 1242.00 375.00** 1.96
**124.11 143.43 296.91 230.32** 10.70
**0.00 6.60 112.99 375.00** 17.50
**0.00 186.66 14.82 375.00** 8.23
```

The one.txt file in dir2 is:

```
**577.44 177.3 623.96 216.78** 0.99988
**584.1 175.32 627.69 210.83** 0.99969
**642.79 172.54 677.84 204.78** 0.99957
**691.79 167.19 822.07 266.94** 0.99954
**575.82 175.05 625.14 216.53** 0.99945
**594.46 175.42 631.45 207.24** 0.99944
**670.44 179.04 742.98 226.7** 0.99904
**635.75 174.77 672.48 201.91** 0.99855
**629.13 174.95 664.3 201.22** 0.99834
**623.4 175.88 654.98 198.93** 0.99771
```

For each element (except the 5th) in line 1 in one.txt file in dir 1 compare all the first four element in all the lines in one.txt file in dir2. And if very close numbers lets say a difference of 1 or 2 between each four elements are found then print them or do something. This is one way to compare but I am open for ideas for comparing content of these two files.

My code is:

```
import os


dir1 = "/home/test"


dir2 = "/home/test1"

for file in os.listdir(dir1):
    file2 = os.path.join(dir2, file)
    if os.path.exists(file2):
        file1 = os.path.join(dir1, file)
        print(file)
        with open(file1, "r") as f1, open(file2, "r") as f2:
            **# how to do the comparison?
            # how to compare first four element of line 1 of f1 with all the first four 
              element of each line of f2 ?**
            same = True
            while True:
                line1 = f1.readline()
                line2 = f2.readline()
                # one way to compare but is not very logical and thorough
                if line1 != line2:
                    same = False
                    break
                if len(line1) == 0:
                    break
            if same:
                print("files are same")
            else:
                print("files are different")
```

Comment: You're not removing the last field before you compare.

Answer (score 0):

Split the lines and slice this to get the first 4 fields.

```
while True:
    line1 = f1.readline().split()[:4]
    line2 = f2.readline().split()[:4]
    if line1 != line2:
        same = False
        break
    if len(line1) == 0:
        break
```

Comment: Another logic i want to implement is: if the first element of first line of first file (i.e 577.44) divided by first element of first line of file in second dir(i.e. 577.44) is less then say 1.1  and second element divide by second element is less then 1.1 ,and  third element divided by third element is 1.1 and same for fourth. If all this condition satisfies then write the entire line of the first file to a new file. Repeat this for all the lines in both the files. How can I achieve that? I am very new to programming, i would really appreciate your help

Comment: `if all(el1/el2 < 1.1 for el1, el2 in zip(line1, line2))`

Comment: this I believe will compare only the first element, but I cant to compare first and second and third and fourth

Comment: It compares each element. Don't you see the `for` loop?

Comment: the data is read as string and that is why I am getting error: if all(el1/el2 < 1.1 for el1, el2 in zip(line1, line2)):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
as / is not supported for str division, where should I convert the value to float to remove this error? Sorry I am very new to programming, just started learning it.

Comment: Convert them to numbers before dividing: `if all(float(el1)/float(el2) < 1.1 for el1, el2 in zip(line1, line2))`

Comment: there are some points with value '0' and that is the reason I am getting this error: if all(float(el1)/float(el2) < 1.1 for el1, el2 in zip(line1, line2)):
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Comment: How should those be treated in the condition? Should they be ignored, should they cause the condition to fail?

Comment: they should not be ignored as these are the co-ordinate values of an object in an image.

Comment: So how should they be treated when doing the division?

Comment: I am basically trying to find similar bounding boxes from two different algorithm. The first four elements are the  cordinates ( x center, y center, x, y). The files are generated by two algorithms seperately and I am comparing them to see if they are close to each other or not( and how many are close) . So, I am using division to see if they are close to each other or not. for.e.g 703/702 = 1.001 which is less then 1.1 so it is good, but some may have value 0, and I am thinking if this is the right way to do it or not, may be I should use subtraction, your suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Division seems like a poor method for this. 1 and 2 are close to each other, but 100 and 200 are not, yet they have the same quotient.

Comment: that is exactly what I am thinking right now, I think subtraction would be a better method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238852/discussion-between-soodep-dhakal-and-barmar).

Comment: I still am not getting the result as expected: even with the subtraction.

Comment: You could divide the difference by the larger of the two numbers. That way you'll never divide by 0 (unless both numbers are 0 -- you could check for equality first).

Comment: Or you could just check for `el2 == 0` and handle that specially.